# Hybrid Auth Blank screen on hauth.start

Tags: php, firefox, facebook-login, hybridauth

I have used hybrid auth in many project and for every project its working fine. But now I am facing an issue with firefox.
When i tried to login via any social media it takes me to this URL

**defined base_url**?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1438286887

and nothing happens after that. Every thing is working fine in Chrome but for firefox its not working.

Comment: please add the raw output from visiting the URL you specified. is base_url a piece of code you wrote? what mime type is specified in its response?

Comment: @Barett Sorry... Base URL is actually the path for hybrid auth end point. its required in configuration.
While inspecting in firebug its showing 500 Internal server error and in response content-type is text/html

Comment: are there any additional (POST) parameters in the request? are they valid?

Comment: Nothing else. This is the URL called by hybrid auth class

Comment: I am having the exactly same issue and was about to post here, in my case its working on localhost but not on production server